# Cypher Remove Duplicate nodes based on propriety

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to remove duplicate nodes on hundreds of records, the same message can be inserted many times.

My first attempt is

```
START n=node(*), m=node(*)
WHERE HAS (n.msgid) AND HAS (m.msgid) AND n.msgid=m.msgid AND id(n)<id(m)
DELETE n
```

But this is extremely slow, anyone has a better performing alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a cross product of all your nodes.

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Label(msgid);

MATCH (n)
WHERE n.msgid
MATCH (m:Label {msgid:n.msgid})
WHERE id(n)<id(m)
DELETE n
```

Comment: I tried to play with the match but I was using ON MATCH and was getting error, will try your method!